# UILineBreakModeTailTruncation is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, deprecated

I am getting an error saying UILineBreakModeTailTruncation is deprecated, any suggestions?

```
[[self.userButton titleLabel] setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`. It tells you what to use instead.

Answer (score 34):

You have to use `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version:

`lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail`

Answer (score -1):

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSLineBreakMode) {        /* What to do with long lines */
    NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,         /* Wrap at word boundaries, default */
    NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,        /* Wrap at character boundaries */
    NSLineBreakByClipping,        /* Simply clip */
    NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,    /* Truncate at head of line: "…wxyz" */
    NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,    /* Truncate at tail of line: "abcd…" */
    NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle    /* Truncate middle of line:  "ab…yz" */
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

we use this emnu now!